# (CISCO) Packet tracer (8.2.1) installation error / not installing Ubuntu (through package installer)

Tags: ubuntu

When installing packet tracer (downloaded from Cisco) through package installer ( app store service)

Packet tracer installation on Ubuntu returns -

'.......pre-installation script subprocess returned exit status 1' error

*It also complains about unmet dependencies but doesn't point out what are those.*

and installation crashes.

Comment: how are you installing *what*? What exactly yields that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app store complains about unmet dependencies, but there are no such as I experienced.
**It should be installed by the terminal.**

- Go to the downloaded file > properties > tick allow  execution
- go to the terminal > cd to Downloads (case sensitive)
- use this command - `sudo dpkg -i Packet_Tracer821_amd64_signed.deb` (might change depending on your version, check the file name)
- installation should be hassle-free > enter TAB to move the selection to "OK"

Comment: You never mentioned the unment dependencies in the question – so that's new info you're giving about the problem in your answer! Could you move that piece of info to your question, instead?

Comment: Very sorry, rectifying that, actually the ' status 1 ' was my point of focus.... That is not available in any search result. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks for posting a question and an answer here!